# Light weight packaging tool

Tags: linux

I am looking for a good way to install an application I developed with all its dependencies in a fancy way. Currently I have a big make file that downloads, unpacks, compiles and installs all dependencies. This however is a little tedious, since there are quite a few dependencies and the make file is getting larger and larger which eventually will be hard to maintain. Therefore I am looking for a packaging tool with the following features:

- It should be a light weight package manager which is very easy to install (or even installs itself and afterwards all my dependencies)
- The destination of the installed binaries, libraries etc. should be customizable
- Each installation process of a dependency should be easy configurable
- It should be possible to include self written scripts that get executed at a specific point during the installation process (in order to manipulate make files, flags etc)
- No admin rights should be necessary since all clients that install my application will not have admin rights and are not able to use an already installed package manager

I do not know if this kind of software exists. I myself don't have much of experience with packaging tools.

Thx in advance for any link, hint, suggestion!

Comment: How do you plan to install dependencies without admin rights? Are you sure that your deps do not require it? If so, and everything is installed local to the user, why not just use multiple Makefiles to make it more maintainable. I think most users would be ok with `tar` and `make`. Two commands are not that bad.

Comment: @drharris I agree, but we are talking about ten or more dependencies where some of them need special attention in tweaking the make process etc. Currently, I make the user use `tar` and `make` to install the dependencies but I want to make the installation process and the maintenance of the dependencies easier and not user dependent ;)

Comment: Understood. In this case I'm looking forward to answers; it's not an easy feat to have a real package manager that doesn't require admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

opkg is something thats based on ipkg (now defunct) and originally dpkg. Its used in embedded systems. Light weight for sure.

Answer (score 0):

ports from crux linux (www.crux.nu)?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search returns [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/features). I would propose make debs and rpms and tarballs and stick with standard installation process (root privileges and such)m but if you can't do that, then, well, you can't.

I'm sure you know how suspicious it would look for the user.

Comment: I agree. And I hate it not having root access! But since the software will only be deployed within my company (at least at the moment) I can live with the suspicious looks ;).